# Animate RecyclerView item - Update for Android Jetpack and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-jetpack

I'm a little bit confused on how apply animations to an item of Recycle View since:

- RecyclerView have been changed a lot of times
- Android Jetpack for animation is out

I don't want a complete guide, just a direction where to point.

I'd like to implement this animation:

[image]

In my case it start when I click on an Item of my RecyclerView.

I don't need that the item is shared between activities since I want to implement this animation in the same Activity. How would you achieve that?

Comment: You can take a look at shared element animation , take a look here [link](https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/index.html)

Comment: Is 2 years old, I doubt that is updated with Jetpack.
Also how can I achieve that in the same activity, not different?